# Print to pdf that is searchable and selectable from existing pdf that is selectable and searchable

Tags: pdf, adobe, searchable

I am trying to print a section of an existing pdf to a new pdf. The original is searchable and selectable but the new pdf cannot do either. I am using "adobe acrobat reader DC" and print via "Microsoft Print to PDF". Unsure if there is any other relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a period of time I could not find an answer that allows for direct PDF to PDF print.

I did find a workaround however.
I downloaded a free software called PrimoPDF. Once installed, PrimoPDF becomes a printer option within Adobe acrobat reader. I then selected my desired pages and printed to PrimoPDf instead of Microsoft Print to PDF. This Generated a .ps file. I then imported the .ps file into PrimoPDF application and was able to generate a .pdf from that. The newly generated pdf was searchable and selectable and exactly what I needed.

Hopefully someone else finds this useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Generally refrying (printing to PostScript then converting back to PDF) is a bad idea. The reason that Microsoft Print to PDF created a file that wasn't searchable is because when Adobe Reader detects that the printer it is targeting isn't capable of rendering the PDF correctly because of any number of reasons, like it doesn't have the right fonts for example, it will render the PDF itself and send an image to the printer. A simpler PDF probably would have worked just fine.

You are much better off getting a tool that will simply allow you to extract the pages you need to a new file rather than printing.